# Ninject (IoC) and an alternative to a factory with conditional logic

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have run into a scenario that I would like to solve with Ninject but up until this point none of my work with it has cross this type of situation.

WCF Service App

W3C Log Parsing App (overly simplistic for demonstration purposes).

IW3CLogItem implemented by W3CLogItem
W3CLogItem has a public member of type IUrlData (contains the important data but can be one of 5 concrete implementations depending on what it contains).

The decision of which concrete implementation to use is based off of a string match and its constructor takes a regex pattern it will use to parse the data as well as the string to be parsed.

Currently I have a simple factory that does the string comparisons and then calls Create() to return a new concrete object (DocumentUrlItem, DriverUrlItem, AssetUrlItem, etc...).

I was looking at the wiki docs and how to name a binding, but even that only gets me half of the way.

The question I have is: Can this be done without a factory? Can I somehow place a conditional attribute on a binding (i.e. .contains, etc...) that evaluates to true to know which binding to use or am I better off sticking with the factory?

Let elaborate a bit.

If I were to write the factory without ninject in a simplified way, it would look like this:

```
protected IUrlData Create(string urldata)
{
    if (urldata.Contains("bob"))
    {
        return new BobUrlData(urldata)
    }
    else if (urldata.Contains("tim"))
    {
        return new TimUrlData(urldata);
    }  
}
```

A couple of things of note:

1) The number of classes that implement IUrlData will grow over time. The strings "tim", and "bob" will be coming from a database.

2) The urldata being passed into BobUrlData and TimUrlData is not the only parameter in the real world, there will also be a regular expression (also sourced from the database which is calculated by the entries timestamp that knows how to handle that particular entry as they have evolved over time.

3) I am really curious if this can be accomplished with Ninject without the need for the factory all together, to somehow through metadata or names achieve the same work but all through bindings all while leaving the code extensible but read-only (other than the binding modules).

Answer (score 0):

You are able to bind to methods with Ninject.

[Ninject Wiki - Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#using-the-request-context-in-a-factory-or-factory-method-to-do-contextual-binding)

You shouldn't need the factory anymore if you set up the method to return what you need. I can't say one is better than the other though since they both work, but I do prefer the factory doing the work and having that access Ninject to give me the correct implementation. Your result is still the same in the end.

Also, right above on the same page is [Specifying Constraints](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#specifying-constraints-on-the-type-binding-using-arbitrary-elements-of-the-resolution-request-context).

Comment: I have read all of the documentation and about 15 other sites and .When() keeps coming up. I am having a hard time understanding how to get IParameter involved to resolve the issue. 

Essentially what it boils down to is I need to figure out (if possible) is how to evaluate one of the parameters in the constructor to decide which binding to use. 

This is an example of what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267368/ninject-conditional-binding-based-on-parameter-type

Answer (score 0):

from a purist point of view, an abstract factory is the correct way to abstract out the implementation from the interface of an object. with that said, ninject offers various ways of implementing what you want without using an abstract factory. The ones that I feel will help you most are [ToMethod](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#using-the-request-context-in-a-factory-or-factory-method-to-do-contextual-binding) and [providers](https://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Providers%20and%20the%20Activation%20Context)

Comment: Nicolas, I hear you and maybe my answer is to move the abstract factory to its own assembly. Essentially what I am trying to achieve (possibly overreaching with my IoC container of choice) is to be able to drop in a new library which implements IUrlData without recompilation of the entire project. My Ninject binding module is already separated out so if I could achieve this easily though the framework it would be a win-win. However the same behavior could be achieved by moving the location of the abstract factory.

Comment: my point is, whether you use an abstract factory or ninject's builtin methods, you're relying on the same pattern (a provider is basically an abstract factory, and the ToMethod binding is a factory method). Using ninject, however, you'll always have to recompile the composition root each time you change one of the dependencies. if you want to be able to change dependencies without recompiling the project, you'll have to look at a DI container that supports configuring dependency resolution in your app.config file. Most DI Containers do this, but not ninject.

Comment: castle windsor is one of the most prominent DI Containers that supports configuring via app.config. It's also one of the most mature frameworks, and supports many advanced DI constructs, like conditional binding and interception